# Dojo : Use of declarative combobox with programmatic jsonreststore

Tags: dojo

This is the JSON from my REST Server:

> [{"name":"REL"},{"name":"RBOW"},{"name":"EMLAWEB"}]

This is the programmatic creation of the JSON data store:

```
    dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    var appPrefixStore = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({target:"http://localhost:9080/AtRest/AtRest/tag/prefix"});`
```

This is the declaratively use of the data store in the comboxbox:

```
    <input id="selectPrefixCombo" 
    name="appPrefix" 
    data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboxBox"
    data-dojo-props="autocomplete:'false', trim:'true', maxHeight:'200', store:'appPrefixStore'">
 </input>
```

However, nothing can displayed in the combobox.  What gives?

I have even tried declaratively use of the data store:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojo.data.JsonRestStore" ...
```

Comment: Did you check that your Store is Loaded with the rest data or not?

Comment: How to I check?  I am using Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,  Apparently I may have been misled by all the tutorials and examples I have seen.
Constructing the JsonRestStore is insufficient to trigger a request to the server.  I have to add an `appPrefixStore.fetch()` to make it work.

Comment: Actually I am correcting myself. Someone else in another forum point out that I have been using the variable in the wrong scope and as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway... here's the working code by using global variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //global variable container
    var widgets = {};

    require(
        // Set of module identifiers
        [   "dojo", 
            "dojo/parser", 
            "dojo/_base/xhr",
            "dijit/form/ComboBox",  
            "dojo/store/JsonRest", 
        ],
        // Callback function, invoked on dependencies evaluation results        
        function(JsonRestStore) {
            widgets.appPrefixStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest({target:"http://localhost:9080/AtRest/AtRest/tag/prefix"});
        });
</script>

<select id="selectPrefixCombo" name="appPrefix" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox"
    data-dojo-props="autocomplete:'false', trim:'true', maxHeight:'200', store:widgets.appPrefixStore">
</select>
```